# If set $A = \{ n: n = 2k \text{ for some } k \in Z \}$ and $B = \{ n: n = 4k \text{ for some } k \in Z \}$ show that $A \neq B$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If set $A = \{ n: n = 2k \text{ for some } k \in Z \}$ and $B = \{ n: n = 4k \text{ for some } k \in Z \}$ show that $A \neq B$.

My solution is attached but it shows both are equal.

> [image]

This logically can not be possible as $A = \{2, 6, 8, 10\ldots\}$ and $B = \{4, 8, 16, 20,\ldots\}$

I don't know how to prove them unequal

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 2):

$2\not \in B$ while $2\in A$, so there are elements that are not in both of them, thus are not equal